# Multiplying two radicals with negatives, simple algebra?

Tags: complex-numbers

Evaluate
$$
\sqrt{-9}\sqrt{-4}
$$
Now, I am told that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$, so I should be able to simply write
$$
\sqrt{-9}\sqrt{-4} = \sqrt{(-9)(-4)}=\sqrt{36} = 6
$$
However, I am also told that I can simplify things like $\sqrt{-9}$ to $\sqrt{9(-1)}=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{-1}=3i$.  Following this reasoning, instead of the above value of 6 I get
$$
\sqrt{-9}\sqrt{-4}=\sqrt{9(-1)}\sqrt{4(-1)}=(3i)(2i)=6i^2=-6
$$
So is the answer $\pm6$?  The first line of thought does not seem to be missing anything but does not include $-6$.  The second line does not include the $6$.  Are both simultaneously needed for completeness?

Comment: "I am told that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$". Without quantifiers, this isn't a statement. When you add the quantifiers to the given equality, then you'll either realize what's wrong or someone will readily point it out for you.

Comment: $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$ is valid only when at least one of $a,b$ is non-negative.